# Error in removing and updating linux-image

Tags: package-management, grub, elementary-os

Whenever i try to update Elementary OS i get the following error

```
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic (3.13.0-32.57) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-32-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-32-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: GRUB: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic (3.13.0-32.57) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-32-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-32-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: GRUB: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic
 linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to remove the package manually but it just returns an error.

Comment: [See if this helps](http://askubuntu.com/a/203808)

Comment: Sadly it did not help

Comment: Try to google some of those errors. For example I found: http://serverfault.com/questions/642032/zz-update-grube-exited-with-return-code-127 This probably isn't it, but may give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to solved the error. I opened the file

```
/etc/default/grub
```

and found on line 11

```
GRUB _ CMDLINE _ LINUX _ DEFAULT="quiet splash acpiosi=linux
```

Removing the spaces between `_` to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpiosi=linux
```

solved the problem